# Adding a string to an array and giving it a numerical value

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I want to add text from an input into an array and assign it a variable based on when it was added, eg if I input "bike", it would be added to the array and then it would print "Your item is number 1" and then input again a different word and it would be number 2 etc.

```
list = []
main = True

shop = input("Enter the shop you are visiting: ")

while main == True:
  
  choice = input("Enter your item: ")
  list.append(choice)
  print("The priority for this item is", list[-1])
```

This is all I have done so far, I did list[-1] not realising it would just print what was added rather than the number position it is in.

Comment: You could just use `len` to print out the length of the list at that point. Otherwise, you could have a counter outside the loop that you increment each time you add (although, that would just give you the length effectively).

Comment: You can use `len(list)` to see how many items are currently in the list, which will be the number of the item that you just added.  i.e. if the list has five items, then the item you just added was obviously the fifth one.

Comment: Not related to the question but it's not recommended to use reserved names like `list` for variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there but with a couple of fixes. First, I changed the name of your list to my_list. Then I used the enumerate function to give your desired output. Try this and see that it works.

```
my_list = []
main = True

shop = input("Enter the shop you are visiting: ")

while main:
  choice = input("Enter your item: ")
  my_list.append(choice)
  for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
      print(f"The priority for item {j} is {i}")
```

Comment: i've never heard of the enumerate function but I can probably find that out myself, im more confused by how you just put "while main:" and the "for i,j" and the "{j}" rather than the use of + or ,

Comment: the `i` keeps track of the index of the item you entered, whilst the `j` is the actual item. I used f-strings to format my output so `{i}` prints the index whilst `{j}` the item. you already did `main = True` in your second line. No need to repeat it again in the while loop.